# Why is the libGDX Timer not functioning with my method?

Tags: java, libgdx

I am writing a game, and I have a function called generateWave(). It spawns enemies, and it functions perfectly when called on it's own, but when it is called after delay by using:

```
Timer.schedule(new Task(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        generateWave(5);
    }
}, 1, 5);
```

Everything is called, but nothing is rendered on the screen. I set up some println's to check how far along in the code it managed to get, and everything did it's job after getting called,  but the result I normally get from calling generateWave() is nowhere to be found. No sprites rendered, despite them being created and placed.

This is the file containing the code: https://github.com/Vynlar/HorseInvaders/blob/master/HorseInvaders/src/me/vynlar/HorseInvaders/world/World.java

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked your code and found the problem. You are adding enemies to list but you also must add it to stage:

```
    for(Enemy enemy : world.getEnemies())
    {
        stage.addActor(enemy);
    }
```

This is from your code from `show()` method(GameScreen.java, line 58), this method is "called when this screen becomes the current screen for a Game.", so if you add your enemies to Enemy list you must all also call `stage.addActor()` to add they to level.

PS. Sorry for my English. I hope that helped you. :)

Comment: Oh, wow. I'm used to writing games where the enemies handle their own rendering, so I managed to forget about the stage. Thank you so much.

Comment: You should totally check that as the answer